# Creating a rails route to an external URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

A lot of my users keep going to `http://(rails app URL)/blog`, but I don't actually have a blog. I finally setup a Posterous blog and now want to direct my users there. Is there a way to configure this using routes.rb? Is there a better way that doesn't involve editing the httpd.conf file?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Depends on the Rails version you are using.

**Rails 3**

```
# in routes.rb
match "/blog" => redirect("http://example.com/blog"), :as => :blog
```

**Rails 2**

```
# in routes.rb
map.blog '/blog',
  :controller => "a_helper_controller",
  :action => "redirect_to_blog"

# in a_helper_controller.rb
def redirect_to_blog
  redirect_to "http://example.com/blog"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any suggestions on what controller to put it in or what to name a new helper controller?

Comment: What if you want to use target="_blank" in your route?
Could be specified a route like this:

    def external_url(); "http://example.com/blog"; end

defined in routes.rb?
I think the only solution for those is define them as helpers.

Answer (score 71):

**I know this is old, so in case someone else needs this for rails 4:**

```
get "/blog" => redirect("http://example.com/blog")
```

*Use get instead of Match in Rails 4, otherwise you'll get a Runtime error*

Comment: This seemed to work for me but I have an issue from a customer using internet explorer:
File Association
Mime Type: application/json, Windows does not recognize this MIME type.

Comment: Very helpful for what I was just working on. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in rails 5? Doesn't seem to work the way it used to in Rails 4 but I can't seem to find resources on this for rails 5. I keep getting a 404.

Answer (score 23):

For Rails 5:

```
get '/stories', to: redirect('/articles')
get '/stories', to: redirect('http://google.com')
```

[Rails Guide source page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

Comment: Worth pointing out that this is a 301 (hard) redirect that could have unintended consequences if it's cached. Might be safer to start with a 302 (soft) redirect first, eg: `get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/articles/%{name}', status: 302)`

Answer (score 4):

**Emulate frontend routes as regular Rails controller routes**

Background : at the beginning there was Rails monolith rendering html view. Then came a frontend React app, and the need to convert the backend to a JSON api, and generate URLs (mostly in emails) pointing to a frontend app that behaves almost exactly like a Rails controller.

I was looking for a way to mimick the rails resource way to construct URL but to point instead to a frontend URL and generate appropriate path_helpers, that could be used easily with my app, RSpec, cucumber/Capybara, and everything else. I found this hack around routes to emulate frontend routes, which also requires an extra param to be passed to completely desambiguate frontend VS backend routes (useful in capybara testing)

```
frontend_scope = {
  as: :frontend,
  host: Rails.configuration.frontend_host, # like https://www.example.com
  port: Rails.configuration.frontend_port, # 443
  constraints: (lambda { |request| request.params[:app] == :frontend })
}
scope(frontend_scope) do
  root to: 'static_pages_controller#home'
  resources :articles, only: [:show, :index]
end
```

Then in my Ruby code I can use

```
frontend_article_url(@article, app: :frontend)
frontend_articles_url(app: :frontend)
... (and everything that can be generated in a classic rails app)
```

The inconvenient is that there will be a `app` parameter in your redirection, that you would have to ignore on your frontend app + all other web apps like Google Analytics, Search engine, etc*.

** the problem being, if you have both a `/articles` on your frontend and a `/articles` on your backend, your app will not be able to make the difference with both routes that resolve to the same URL without the help from an extra param. If you are converting your fullstack app to a Rails API, or if you also need the same routes to handle prerendering/meta for SEO, this can be a problem, otherwise this should be largely cancelled by a /api/ prefix*