# How do I redirect Rails routes to other sites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, redirect

I am trying to write a test case of Rails' routing to redirect to another site.

For example:

```
get "foo/:id",redirect("http://othersite.com/foo/%{id}",:status => 301)
```

The following attempt produced errors:

```
assert_routing "foo/123","http://othersite.com/foo/123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622706/creating-a-rails-route-to-an-external-url) answer, I can suggest the same thing.

**Did you try:**

```
match "/blog" => redirect("http://example.com/blog"), :as => :blog
```

This works for you?