# Adding redirect to Ruby on Rails webpage using .htaccess or Virtualmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide on this issue! I manage a Ruby on Rails website that uses Apache and lives on Joyent's Cloud Server. Right now I have a pdf located at http://example.com/docs/mydoc.pdf . I'd like for this url to 301 redirect visitors to http://example.com/mydoc , which will be a webpage with the same content (instead of a pdf.)

I've tried a couple of methods for getting the redirect to take place, but neither are working.

1. I went into VirtualMin and into the Apache server. Then, I chose Aliases / Redirects. Finally, I went under Permanent URL redirects and entered: FROM http://example.com/docs/mydoc.pdf TO http://example.com/mydoc and applied the changes.
2. Since that didn't work, I went looking for an .htaccess file in my /public folder. None existed. So, I created an .htaccess file and added it to the /public folder. The only code in the file is

`Redirect 301 /docs/mydoc.pdf http://example.com/mydoc`

The problem? When I go to http://example.com/docs/mydoc.pdf, the redirect doesn't work.

I'm looking for the simplest way to add this 301 redirect and future 301 redirects to my website. Thanks again for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3 introduced an easy way to perform 301 redirects from config/routes.rb

```
match "/oldpath", :to => redirect "/newpath"
```

[This site](http://www.camelpunch.com/web-development/tutorials/301-redirect-with-rails/) has a somewhat cumbersome solution for 301 redirects in Rails 2.

However, if I were you I would put all my redirects in an apache config file. This maintains a helpful degree of modularity: you don't have to mix your routes with your redirects, you don't have to mix artifacts of your old website into your new app.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I forgot to mention that the site is built in Rails 2.3.14 (and an upgrade to 3 isn't possible at this time.) How can I do 301 redirects in that version, and is this the preferable way to do it over using an .htaccess file? I'm concerned about the SEO impact.

Comment: I've updated the response with a link to Rails 2 instructions, and also with a reason to stick with .htaccess

Comment: Thanks for your help! I updated my original question as well. Unfortunately, the .htaccess solution isn't working for some reason. When I go to http://example.com/docs/mydoc.pdf, the redirect doesn't take place. Any ideas why?

Comment: I've updated the answer once more. Putting your .htaccess file in your rails directory doesn't matter; rails works quite a bit differently than, say, PHP, and your .htaccess file almost certianly isn't in your root directory. Place your redirects in a config file and include that file into your httpd.conf. Any more specific advice would depend heavily on your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a lot more complicated than I expected to put a single 301 redirect in place. I'm worried that messing around with the configuration could cause other problems. Also, I'm unable to find a httpd.conf file where I think it should be (in the /etc folder). Does this link explain a viable alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622706/creating-a-rails-route-to-an-external-url ?

Comment: That link is a viable solution, but I'm wary of creating a redirects_controller just to deal with changed permalinks. You can find your httpd.conf with the command `httpd -V` as HTTPD_ROOT/SERVER_CONFIG_FILE

Comment: Thanks, @Rpedroso, for all of your responses. I'll explore these three options. Would love to give you points for answers, but still waiting to break the 15 pt reputation barrier!