# Rails route: redirect to external url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I redirect my home root to an external url? I have a backend website and I want to redirect index to another website (and on another domain).

I'm using Rails 4:

```
root to: redirect('http:XXXX')
```

works?

Comment: seems so -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622706/creating-a-rails-route-to-an-external-url  ........oO

Answer (score 1):

The following line will redirect to an external URL.

```
root to: redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work make sure you enter the external URL properly.