# How to use a link helper if I want to create a link for an external url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

If have **about**, **faq** and **contact us** pages on an external domain - a subdomain of my main website, how can I use Rails url helpers to refer to them?

For instance,

```
about page => 'about.my_domain123.com'

contact us page => 'about.my_domain123.com/contact_us' 

faq page => 'about.my_domain123.com/faq'
```

How to tell Rails that about_url/path, faq_url/path and contact_us_url/path should point to the pages above, on the domain "about.my_domain123.com" that is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a rails route to an external URL in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082612/creating-a-rails-route-to-an-external-url-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable subdomain with [constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints):

```
constraints subdomain: 'about' do
    get '/', action: :index, as: :about, controller: :about
    get :contact_us, controller: :about
end
```

and then just use a normal url helper

```
about_url# 'about.localhost:3000/'
```

To test in localhost you will have to add `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0` in `config/environments/development.rb` as described  [here](https://gist.github.com/indiesquidge/b836647f851179589765)