# Rails API with frontend - routing email links to backend or frontend application

Tags: ruby, frontend, ruby-on-rails-5, backend, rails-api

I have a Rails API backend and a ReactJS frontend. My backend sends custom emails that often have confirmation-like links (like email confirmation)

**Should the confirmation links point to my backend directly, or should they rather load the frontend first and then make an API call to the backend?**

The two alternatives I'm thinking of are:

**1 - The email confirmation link hits directly**

`backend.example.com/email_confirmations/:confirmation_token`, which then redirects to a specific success (error) page `frontend.example.com/email_confirmation/success`(`/failure`) on my frontend.

On the backend I would only need a `Metal` controller with minimum modules to perform redirection to the frontend app, the controller is always responding with redirects). If further actions need to be taken from the frontend, they'll hit a different API Endpoint

**2 - The email confirmation links opens up my frontend at**

`frontend.example.com/email_confirmations/:confirmation_token` that triggers an API request to `backend.example.com/email_confirmations/:confirmation_token`.

Then my (Json:api) backend makes a jsonapi-compliant response with a Rails `APIController`.

**What are you doing in practice?**

I decided to opt in for the first scenario but maybe systematically calling/loading the frontend first makes more sense?

**How do you wire backend/frontend in those scenarios?**

I have currently implemented a very simple (`Metal`) Controller that would just process the incoming parameters perform redirections only to the frontend. I was hoping to define "url helpers" that would point to my frontend like so:

```
namespace :email_redirection do 
    # Controller that gets hit by email confirmation links in scenario #1
    resources :confirmations
end

namespace :frontend do
    frontend_root = Rails.configuration.frontend_host_with_http_and_port

    scope frontend_root do
      # Generation of URL Helpers for the frontend app
      resources :confirmations, only: [] do
        get 'successful'
        get 'unsuccessful'
      end
    end
end
```

And my confirmation controller would be like

```
class EmailRedirection::ConfirmationsController
  def index
    svc = MyConfirmationService.new(token: params[:confirmation_token])
    if svc.confirm
      redirect_to(
        frontend_successful_confirmation_url,
        email: svc.confirmable.email
      )
      else
        redirect_to(frontend_unsuccessful_confirmation_url)
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm getting several error and I believe maybe the url helpers are not useable with different host/port... (or I have to pass them explicitely to each call)

How can I handle that ? And if 1. is a good choice, what would be the redirection codes you'd send on success/failure (since they can only be 3xx) ?

Both solutions involve quite some wiring between the backend/frontend and I'm not sure how to best wire things up.

*Note : my models use devise but because devise isn't so great with APIs/etc. I'm using my own ConfirmationService that also handles some side-effects. I don't consider Devise to be relevant here*

[Creating a rails route to an external URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622706/creating-a-rails-route-to-an-external-url)

Answer (score -1):

Both approaches have their pros and cons, and the choice between them depends on your specific requirements and preferences. Let's break down each approach:

- Direct Backend Confirmation Link:
  This approach is straightforward and involves minimal additional frontend logic and confirmation logic is processed on the server side before redirecting to the frontend.
  However, users would make an additional request when they click the confirmation link, hitting the backend first and then being redirected to the frontend.users experience slightly slower speed due to the additional redirect.
- Frontend Handles API Request
  in this approach, users go directly to the frontend, providing a smoother user experience also, You have more control over the frontend flow and can handle errors gracefully.
  On the other hand, the frontend needs to handle the API request and potentially show loading indicators until the request is complete.In addition,
  exposing confirmation tokens in frontend URLs may pose a security risk.
  NOTE: Make sure to handle the API request asynchronously to prevent blocking the user interface.

---

If you're facing issues with URL helpers due to different hosts/ports between the frontend and backend, you can specify the host explicitly when generating the URLs. In Rails, you can achieve this by passing the host parameter to the URL helper:

```
redirect_to frontend_successful_confirmation_url(host: 'frontend.example.com', email: svc.confirmable.email)
```

For success, you can use 302 Found or 303 See Other for the redirection. For failure, you can use 4xx status codes (e.g., 400 Bad Request for client errors) or 5xx status codes (e.g., 500 Internal Server Error for server errors).